# Devise: Log user out after the confirmation period ends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

Devise has a way of allowing users to login without confirming their email immediately by setting the allow_unconfirmed_access_for config var.

I have a setup for logging the user out of the application once the confirmation period ends. Also, I need the user to be only logged out at night at 2 AM.

For this, I overrode the confirmation_period_valid? method in the confirmable module of devise for some custom logic -

**Original Devise Method -**

```rb
def confirmation_period_valid?
  return true if self.class.allow_unconfirmed_access_for.nil?
  return false if self.class.allow_unconfirmed_access_for == 0.days

  confirmation_sent_at && confirmation_sent_at.utc >= self.class.allow_unconfirmed_access_for.ago
end
```

**Overriden method I defined in the user model file.**

```rb
def confirmation_period_valid?
  confirmation_time = confirmation_sent_at.in_time_zone(time_zone).end_of_day + 2.hours
  unconfirmed_access_time = self.class.allow_unconfirmed_access_for.ago.in_time_zone(time_zone)
  confirmation_sent_at && confirmation_time >= unconfirmed_access_time
end
```

But when I check after the expiration period, I am still able to use the application. The user is not logged out.

Checking the rails console shows that the confirmation period is not valid for the user so that works.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How is this method being called? What code is in your controllers? Presumably there must be something along the lines of `log_out unless confirmation_period_valid?`, but since you haven't shown us how this is implemented, I can only speculate what the issue might be.

Comment: Ah, I just realised this is specifically about `Devise` ... But even so, *how exactly* are you "overriding" the method? Only showing us a method definition, out of context, doesn't reveal much about your implementation.

Comment: I updated the question. Basically, I overrode the confirmation_period_valid? method of devise confirmable for some custom logic. I assumed on the end of the period, devise would required authentication again for the user but somehow this does not work.

Comment: [The devise README](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) says "Confirmable: .... verifies whether an account is already confirmed **during sign in**." So, what exactly did you mean by "still able to use the application"? Are you saying that a user who's already signed in doesn't get logged out (which isn't what I'd expect to happen anyway, based on that description), or are you saying that the user is still somehow able to log in?

Comment: The reason I asked about if there's any code in your controllers is that if you're expecting this check to happen on *every request* then it would surely need to be part of a `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`. (...Or alternatively, you could have only given an initial authentication token with a short expiry, but that wasn't discussed at all in your post.)

Comment: Devise has a way of allowing users to login without confirming their email immediately by setting the allow_unconfirmed_access_for config var. After the unconfirmed access is over, it should log the user out. Apologies for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... Looking carefully through your logic, I think there are several issues.

I don't know what value you set `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` to, because you haven't told us, but for the sake of this answer let's arbitrarily assume it's **1 day**. Now, your code says the following:

```
def confirmation_period_valid?
  # This is a confusing variable name.
  # It's more like an unconfirmed access *expiry* time
  confirmation_time = confirmation_sent_at.in_time_zone(time_zone).end_of_day + 2.hours

  # This makes no sense. Why is the user always "unconfirmed" 1 day ago?
  unconfirmed_access_time = self.class.allow_unconfirmed_access_for.ago.in_time_zone(time_zone)

  # if confirmation_sent_at == nil then the method would have blown up in line 1
  # so this check is poorly placed. And the second part is just wrong --
  # you're asking if the user was supposed to be logged out more than a day ago, not now!
  confirmation_sent_at && confirmation_time >= unconfirmed_access_time
end
```

So... Here's what I think you actually meant to write instead:

```
def confirmation_period_valid?
  # Note: allow_unconfirmed_access_for is completely redundant in the logic now!
  return false unless confirmation_sent_at

  unconfirmed_access_expires_at = confirmation_sent_at.in_time_zone(time_zone).end_of_day + 2.hours
  unconfirmed_access_expires_at > Time.current
end
```

Now with that said, I do think this is an over-engineered solution, and you could have just stuck with the default behaviour of `allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.day` rather than adding in this arbitrary 2am logic, but as you like it...